# Landsat 5 data gaps in the 90s in Alaska

Tags: landsat

I'm working on looking at all available Landsat imagery for coastal Alaska, particularly above the Arctic circle. There are significant data gaps in the available imagery in the 90s when Landsat 5 was in operation (see attached image). I've been trying to figure out if there was a specific problem during this window for high latitude data acquisition, or if this is just an unfortunate coincidence of working in the Arctic. Does anyone know anything about this?

The image availability counts shown are for 1 specific location in Western AK and includes a filter for specific times and quality pulled from Google Earth Engine (ice free summer season, 50% cloud filter), but this pattern held across northern AK and regardless of filters applied.

Note that I am well aware of the limitations of working in the Arctic as relates to EO data and availability. I am just wondering if anyone is aware of any specific problems with Landsat 5 during this time window that  might have impacted data availability. [image]

Comment: If this is open data then I think the place to ask about its data gaps is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.